# Где найти документацию на API ADO в Delphi 7?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, ado

На ADO буду реализовывать интерфейс работы с БД, поэтому хотелось бы найти нормальное руководство. Работаю в Delphi 7.

Answer (score 2):

Нашел сам же по запросу "ado vcl api" :
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/ado-api-reference

Comment: :) тут всё дело в том, что ADO - это технология Microsoft, а не Borland. Поэтому API нужно искать не в VCL, а именно у MS. Правда - немного непонятно, чем Вас не устроили штатные TADOConnection, TADOStoredProc, TADOQuery (обертки над ADO-интерфейсами)